# Using touchesBegan & touchesEnded as Swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I'm trying to see if a user swiped all the way from one view, label, etc. to another.

Here is my relevant Code
ViewController.h :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *swipeBegin;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *swipeEnd;
```

TextField : To display if the whole thing was successful.
SwipeBegin : The Label from which the swipe begins.
SwipeEnd : The Label where the swipe is supposed to end.
ViewController.m :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if ([touch view] == swipeBegin) {
    gestureStartPointTouched = YES;
}
```

If the swipe began at "swipeBegin" a bool value is set to YES.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if ([touch view] == swipeEnd) {        
    if (gestureStartPointTouched == YES) {
        [TextField setText:@"Success"];
    }
}
```

If I start swiping at "swipeBegin" the touchesBegan method is called -> works fine
The troubling part is the touchesEnded method.

```
if([touch view] == swipeEnd)
```

is false no matter what i do about it.

Does anybody have an advice ?

Thank You !

## Solution

Editing the touchesEnded method :

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
if ([self.view hitTest:[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view] withEvent:event] == SwipeEnd) {
    if (gestureStartPointTouched == YES) {
        [TextField setText:@"Success"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view of the touch never changes, if it starts in swipeBegin that will always be it's view. If you want to find out where it ended use `hitTest:withEvent:` with the touch's end location, that will return the view you are looking for.